# Identifying a standard gettext pot file

Tags: gettext, php-gettext

Within my php framework (CakePHP), is a i18n tool for generating POT files. The header of the file is generated like so:

```
protected function _writeHeader() {
    $output = "# LANGUAGE translation of CakePHP Application\n";
    $output .= "# Copyright YEAR NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n";
    $output .= "#\n";
    $output .= "#, fuzzy\n";
    $output .= "msgid \"\"\n";
    $output .= "msgstr \"\"\n";
    $output .= "\"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"POT-Creation-Date: " . date("Y-m-d H:iO") . "\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"PO-Revision-Date: YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM+ZZZZ\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"Last-Translator: NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"MIME-Version: 1.0\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\\n\"\n";
    $output .= "\"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\\n\"\n\n";
    return $output;
}
```

I am curious to know if the following:

```
$output .= "#, fuzzy\n";
$output .= "msgid \"\"\n";
$output .= "msgstr \"\"\n";
```

breaks some sort of standards of gettext. If it does not, I would love an explanation as to why one would put that in the header of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's 'fuzzy' because the headers are not complete. i.e. the template entries will be filled in when the PO files are generated from the POT.

The official Gettext `xgettext` tool that generates POT files from source code also adds the fuzzy flag to the header. By that token it is certainly not against the standard.

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes perfect sense. what about the msgid and msgstr, should those be there?

Comment: I just install Ubuntu and searched for examples. I do see the msgid and msgstr in the header and blank.

Comment: Thank apparently blank `msgstr ""` actually indicates a multi-line entry. i.e. the entire header block is a single entry in the file with an empty `msgid` and a multi-line `msgstr`. I was confused by this when I first saw a PO file. It took me a while to work that out.